# How to fix TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable?

Tags: python, function, typeerror, sympy

```
def f(x):
    f='exp(x)-x-2'
    y=eval(f)
    print(y)
    return y
def bissection(f,f_line,f_2lines,a,b,epsilon1,epsilon2):
    x=a
    result_a=f(a)
    x=b
    result_b=f(b)
    if (f.evalf(a)*f.evalf(b)>=0):
        print("Interval [a,b] does not contain a zero ")
        exit()
    zeta=min(epsilon1,epsilon2)/10
    x=a
    while(f_line(x)>0):
        if(x<b or x>-b):
            x=x+zeta
        else:
            stop  
    ak=a
    bk=b
    xk=(ak+bk)/2
    k=0
    if (f(xk)*f(ak)<0):
        ak=ak
        bk=xk
    if (f(xk)*f(bk)<0):
        ak=xk
        bk=bk
    k=k+1
from sympy import *
import math
x=Symbol('x')
f=exp(x)-x-2
f_line=f.diff(x)                   
f_2lines=f_line.diff(x)           
print("Derivative of f:", f_line)    
print("2nd Derivative of f:", f_2lines) 
a=int(input('Beginning of interval: '))
b=int(input('End of interval: '))
epsilon1=input('1st tolerance: ')
epsilon2=input('2nd tolerance: ')
bissection(f,f_line,f_2lines,a,b,epsilon1,epsilon2)
```

This program is an attempt to implement the Bissection Method. I've tried writing two functions:

The first one, f, is supposed to receive the extremes of the interval that may or may not contain a root (a and b) and return the value of the function evaluated in this point.

The second one, bissection, should receive the function, the function's first and second derivatives, the extremes of the interval (a,b) and two tolerances (epsilon1,epsilon2).

What I want to do is pass each value a and b, one at a time, as arguments to the function f, that is supposed to return f(a) and f(b); that is, the values of the function in each of the points a and b.

Then, it should test two conditions:
1) If the function values in the extremes of the intervals have opposite signs. If they don't, the method won't converge for this interval, then the program should terminate.

```
if(f.evalf(a)*f.evalf(b)>=0)
    exit()
```

2)

```
while(f_line(x)>0): #while the first derivative of the function evaluated in x is positive
    if(x<b or x>-b):     #This should test whether x belongs to the interval [a,b]
        x=x+zeta                                #If it does, x should receive x plus zeta
    else:
        stop
```

At the end of this loop, my objective was to determine whether the first derivative was strictly positive (I didn't do the negative case yet).

The problem: I'm getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "bissec.py", line 96, in <module>
       bissection(f,f_line,f_2lines,a,b,epsilon1,epsilon2)
   File "bissec.py", line 41, in bissection
       result_a=f(a)
TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

How can I properly call the function so that it returns the value of the function (in this case, f(x)=exp(x)-x-2), for every x needed? That is, how can I evaluate f(a) and f(b)?

Comment: first made code more readable. Put imports at the beginnig, add empty lines and spaces around chars like `=`. See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: you use the same name `f` for `def f(x)` and `f = exp(x)-x-2` and maybe it makes problem - Python may use different `f` then you expect.

Comment: I don't see any actual problem with the use of the expression `f = 'exp(x)-x-2'`. I've tested and it works. I recommend you to not use the same name for a variable and a function, as these multiple definitions can colide.

Comment: you have problem in line `result_a=f(a)` but later you don't use `result_a` - so maybe simply remove this line.

Comment: Also, could you add some input examples and expected outputs?

Comment: @DanielLavedoniodeLima I was able to reproduce the problem using these inputs:

Beginning of interval: 0
End of interval: 1
1st tolerance: 0.001
2nd tolerance: 0.001

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I've figured it out where your program was failing and I've got 4 reasons why.

First of all, and the main topic of your question, if you want to evaluate a function `f` for a determined `x` value, let's say `a`, you need to use `f.subs(x, a).evalf()`, as it is described in [SymPy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html). You used in 2 different ways: `f.evalf(2)` and `f_line(a)`; both were wrong and need to be substituted by the correct syntax.

Second, if you want to stop a while loop you should use the keyword `break`, not "stop", as written in your code.

Third, avoid using the same name for variables and functions. In your `f` function, you also used `f` as the name of a variable. In `bissection` function, you passed `f` as a parameter and tried to call the `f` function. That'll fail too. Instead, I've changed the `f` function to `f_calc`, and applied the correct syntax of my first point in it.

Fourth, your `epsilon1` and `epsilon2` inputs were missing a `float()` conversion. I've added that.

Now, I've also edited your code to use good practices and applied [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

This code should fix this error that you're getting and a few others:

```
from sympy import *


def func_calc(func, x, val):
    """Evaluate a given function func, whose varible is x, with value val"""
    return func.subs(x, val).evalf()


def bissection(x, f, f_line, f_2lines, a, b, epsilon1, epsilon2):
    """Applies the Bissection Method"""

    result_a = func_calc(f, x, a)
    result_b = func_calc(f, x, b)

    if (result_a * result_b >= 0):
        print("Interval [a,b] does not contain a zero")
        exit()

    zeta = min(epsilon1, epsilon2) / 10
    x_val = a
    while(func_calc(f_line, x, a) > 0):
        if(-b < x_val or x_val < b):
            x_val = x_val + zeta
        else:
            break  # the keyword you're looking for is break, instead of "stop"

    print(x_val)
    ak = a
    bk = b
    xk = (ak + bk) / 2
    k = 0
    if (func_calc(f, x, xk) * func_calc(f, x, ak) < 0):
        ak = ak
        bk = xk
    if (func_calc(f, x, xk) * func_calc(f, x, bk) < 0):
        ak = xk
        bk = bk
    k = k + 1


def main():
    x = Symbol('x')
    f = exp(x) - x - 2
    f_line = f.diff(x)
    f_2lines = f_line.diff(x)
    print("Derivative of f:", f_line)
    print("2nd Derivative of f:", f_2lines)
    a = int(input('Beginning of interval: '))
    b = int(input('End of interval: '))
    epsilon1 = float(input('1st tolerance: '))
    epsilon2 = float(input('2nd tolerance: '))
    bissection(x, f, f_line, f_2lines, a, b, epsilon1, epsilon2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much to all, I've managed to get the program to work!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, @MarceloCarvalho. If this answer solved the issue, don't forget to accept it.